# django incorporating ads

Tags: django

I would like to add some ad "zones" to my site and register clicks, impressions of the ads (maybe store results in a mySQL db?). I have been working with Django for sometime now, and would like to continue using the same. However, I have never dealt with ads before.

Is there a plugin of some sort which enables serving ads in Django? I have looked at django-ads, but it dosent look like its been updated for a while, and therefore was not sure if this is the right way to go.

Does anyone have experience using django-ads framework? or are there other plugins to do the same job? Thanks for your time.

Features I am looking for ideally (please let me know if you think there are others you think are required):

```
1] Number of times the ads get displayed
2] Number of clicks on each ad
3] Number of impressions on each ad
4] IP of the click (to identify unique visitors)
```

Comment: It might be worth listing in detail what features you need - if nothing else it may help you think about the effort in rolling your own solution.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, I have edited the post and listed a few requirements now. Do let me know your thoughts.

Comment: To clarify: is this placing your own ads on yours/other people's sites, or you tracking the performance of other people's ads placed on your site?

Comment: @Marcin: It is for tracking performance of other peopls ads placed on my site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are a number of ad networks that provide javascript snippets (usually) to put on your pages, and thats shows the ads. You'll just provide an iframe for the ads to be displayed in. The ad network tracks impressions, clicks, unique users, etc. already. You'll probably get a report with all this info. All you do is register with them, drop the javascript, and (hopefully) start getting paid. Not sure why you'd want to do this yourself.

Obviously the largest ad network is google's AdSense, but if you search for "ad network" you'll come up with a whole truckload of alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was under the impression both parties (myself and the ad network) need to do these tasks (clicks, impressions etc).

Comment: yeah they actually need to track impressions/clicks/users etc. for correct billing (billing the advertiser and paying the publisher). Not completely positive that they provide reports to the publisher but I'm guessing they do.

Answer (score 2):

For people landing here more recently than when the question was asked you have two more options: [django-ads](https://github.com/razisayyed/django-ads) and [django-advertising](https://github.com/mapeveri/django-advertising).